# Check if build was sideloaded or downloaded from App/Play Store

Tags: react-native, production-environment, sideloading, test-environments

React Native uses `__DEV__` internally [to check whether an app is a dev or release build](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/search?p=1&q=__DEV__&unscoped_q=__DEV__).

We use that to determine whether we should point to our staging or production environments.

```
_host = (__DEV__) ? 'https://staging-api.foo-app.com' : 'https://api.foo-app.com';

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  deploymentKey = (__DEV__) // iOS
    ? '5eCkg3JX3aip-D_a77eea5c3-0MXihVlUTZ4yy45a-432a-b73e-0a844d8b8310' // Staging
    : 'zGxOja-Yhchs87eea5c3-0d5a-432aQriLlV17gI-sdj55-b73e-0a844d8b8310'; // Production
} else {
  deploymentKey = (__DEV__) // Android
    ? 'vrrKTaq08Hid77eea5c3-0d5a-432aDhXbdI8-G9CnWmqc-b73e-0a844d8b8310' // Staging
    : '8DclNAKdcQkKlQDL77eea5c3-0d5a-432aslW1SeS6sDMo-b73e-0a844d8b8310'; // Production
}
```

**The problem is that `__DEV__` evaluates to `false` for any builds sideloaded to a device from XCode and Android Studio.** So, to test on a device, we do this in a few places:

```
// _host = (__DEV__) ? 'https://staging-api.foo-app.com' : 'https://api.foo-app.com';
_host = 'https://staging-api.foo-app.com';
```

How can we determine if an app is sideloaded vs downloaded from the App Store or Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having keys and data that switches based on `__DEV__`...might I suggest using various `.env` files using a, *much safer*, 12-factor approach with [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config).

This way you can have deployment keys and environment based variables within files that can be `.gitignore`d.

You can have something like:

**.env** (Staging)

```
HOST=https://staging-api.foo-app.com
DEPLOYMENT_KEY_IOS=5eCkg3JX3aip-D_a77eea5c3-0MXihVlUTZ4yy45a-432a-b73e-0a844d8b8310
DEPLOYMENT_KEY_ANDROID=vrrKTaq08Hid77eea5c3-0d5a-432aDhXbdI8-G9CnWmqc-b73e-0a844d8b8310
```

**.env.production** (Production)

```
HOST=https://api.foo-app.com
DEPLOYMENT_KEY_IOS=vrrKTaq08Hid77eea5c3-0d5a-432aDhXbdI8-G9CnWmqc-b73e-0a844d8b8310
DEPLOYMENT_KEY_ANDROID=8DclNAKdcQkKlQDL77eea5c3-0d5a-432aslW1SeS6sDMo-b73e-0a844d8b8310
```

[react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) instructions should be clear enough on how you'd use each file based off build type.